# how to add two library in javascript google map

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

iam creating route after create route  checkpostion but its error  with geomtry library, i want to add please help me, how do this ,my code below

```
 for (var i = 0; i < overviewPathGeo.length; i++) {
                        triangleCoords.push( [{lat:
       overviewPathGeo[i],  lng: overviewPathGeo[i]}]
    );
                    }


             var bermudaTriangle = new google.maps.Polygon({paths: triangleCoords});


        google.maps.event.addListener(mapse, 'click', function(e) {
          var resultColor =
              google.maps.geometry.poly.containsLocation(e.latLng, bermudaTriangle) ?
              'red' :
              'green';
              alert(resultColor);
               });
```

how to add geometry library , with route library

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?libraries=geometry&sensor=false"></script>
```

i want both how add both, these are conflict

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.21&libraries=places&sensor=false"></script>
```

[image]

Comment: your question is not clear enough to help you

Comment: i want bot libraries in my single page, but its show javascript error

Answer (score 1):

Read the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/libraries) (**Libraries: Overview**, towards the bottom of the page):

> **To request multiple libraries, separate them with a comma:**

```
<script type="text/javascript"
src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY&libraries=geometry,places">
</script>
```